# Split string based on a key word in r programming, keyword= BAS, Getting duplicate results. especially FRM_id = 1014

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape2

```
if (!require("librarian"))install.packages("librarian")
librarian::shelf(stringr,stringi,dplyr,reshape2)


FRM_ID<-c(1006,1007,1011,1012,1014,1014,1015)
FRM_Name<-c("ABMPSNY NSMF BAS  SVFNUF SUPFRMSR BAS M&M BAS PBWFR GRJD ABRP BAS SUN PHSRMS",
"BSJSJ FJNSNAF BAS  LSRSFN BAS NTPA BAS SDSNJ PBRTS  ",
"KBTSK MSHJNDRS WJPRB JSW STEEL    ",
"SSJSN PSJNTS TJTSN ABMPSNY      ",
"EEE FNTFRPRJS BAS CTD NFSTLF      ",
"EEE FNTFRPRJS BAS CTD. NFSTLF.     ",
"MSRUTJ SUZUKJ BAS  XYX CORP BAS       "
)
FRM_DATE <- c('1990-02-02','1990-02-05','1990-02-06','1990-02-06','1990-02-06','1990-02-07','1990-02-08')
Samp_Data<-data.frame(FRM_ID,FRM_Name,FRM_DATE)

SD_New <- Samp_Data %>% 
          filter(grepl(" BAS ",FRM_Name))

SD_New1 <- str_split_fixed(SD_New$FRM_Name," BAS ",5)


SD_New2 <- cbind.data.frame(SD_New1[,1],SD_New1[,2],SD_New1[,3],SD_New1[,4],SD_New1[,5])

SD_New2$FRM_ID <- SD_New$FRM_ID

colnames(SD_New2) <- c("NAME1","NAME2","NAME3","NAME4","NAME5","FRM_ID")

RJ_NEW_NEW2 <- SD_New2 %>% 
               right_join(SD_New,by=c("FRM_ID"))

SD_Melt <- reshape2::melt(RJ_NEW_NEW2,id=c("FRM_ID","FRM_Name","FRM_DATE"))


SD_Melt <- SD_Melt %>% 
           select(FRM_ID,FRM_DATE,value) %>% 
           rename(FRM_Name=value)

SD_Melt <-SD_Melt %>% 
          mutate_all(na_if,"")

SD_Melt[SD_Melt==""]<- NA

SD_Melt_clean <- SD_Melt %>% 
                 filter(!(is.na(FRM_Name)))


SD_Melt_clean <- SD_Melt_clean %>% 
                 filter(nchar(FRM_Name)>1) %>% 
                 unique()
```

Comment: what's the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
library(tidyverse)

Samp_Data %>% 
  filter(grepl(" BAS ",FRM_Name)) %>% 
  separate_rows(FRM_Name, sep = " BAS ") %>% 
  mutate(FRM_Name = trimws(FRM_Name))
```

**Output**

```
   FRM_ID FRM_Name          FRM_DATE  
    <dbl> <chr>             <chr>     
 1   1006 "ABMPSNY NSMF"    1990-02-02
 2   1006 "SVFNUF SUPFRMSR" 1990-02-02
 3   1006 "M&M"             1990-02-02
 4   1006 "PBWFR GRJD ABRP" 1990-02-02
 5   1006 "SUN PHSRMS"      1990-02-02
 6   1007 "BSJSJ FJNSNAF"   1990-02-05
 7   1007 "LSRSFN"          1990-02-05
 8   1007 "NTPA"            1990-02-05
 9   1007 "SDSNJ PBRTS"     1990-02-05
10   1014 "EEE FNTFRPRJS"   1990-02-06
11   1014 "CTD NFSTLF"      1990-02-06
12   1014 "EEE FNTFRPRJS"   1990-02-07
13   1014 "CTD. NFSTLF."    1990-02-07
14   1015 "MSRUTJ SUZUKJ"   1990-02-08
15   1015 "XYX CORP"        1990-02-08
16   1015 ""                1990-02-08
```

Answer (score 0):

In base R do:

```
read.csv(text=gsub(" BAS ", ",", Samp_Data$FRM_Name), header = FALSE, strip.white = TRUE)
                              V1              V2   V3              V4         V5
1                   ABMPSNY NSMF SVFNUF SUPFRMSR  M&M PBWFR GRJD ABRP SUN PHSRMS
2                  BSJSJ FJNSNAF          LSRSFN NTPA     SDSNJ PBRTS           
3 KBTSK MSHJNDRS WJPRB JSW STEEL                                                
4     SSJSN PSJNTS TJTSN ABMPSNY                                                
5                  EEE FNTFRPRJS      CTD NFSTLF                                
6                  EEE FNTFRPRJS    CTD. NFSTLF.                                
7                  MSRUTJ SUZUKJ        XYX CORP
```

Then you can `cbind` it to the original dataframe